Cannot send email with officejs displayNewMessageFormAsync in outlook addin
i am developing outlook addin using office.js but i cannot send email with function
 Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageFormAsync({
                                toRecipients: [contactInfo.emailAddress],
                                subject: subject || "Your Default Subject",
                                body: bodyContent || "This is an auto-generated message.",
                            });

i got the message
Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageFormAsync is not a function
base on the document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-mailbox-displaynewmessageformasync-member(1)
they require version 1.9
but i am not sure which office version i am using event in manifest i add
<Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.9"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>

how to use this api? how to know which office.js version i am using? seems MS document is not clear.

could you provide some sample.. look like the code is correct. may be your code is not running within the office context environment
